# How to get a three-way table displaying the mean of one variable depending on all combinations of two other variables?

Tags: r

I want a three-way table displaying the mean of `a` for all combinations of `b` and `c`.

`table()` and `outer()` give me separately what I want:

```
> with(df1, table(c, b))
    b
c    0 1
  5  1 1
  10 1 2
  15 3 2

> t(outer(0:1, c(5, 10, 15), Vectorize(function(x, y) 
+   with(df1, mean(a[b == x & c == y])))))
         [,1] [,2]
[1,] 17.00000 20.0
[2,] 17.00000 16.5
[3,] 16.66667 15.0
```

How could I combine this, preferably in a base **R** solution?

I tried `ftable()`, which gives me this:

```
> with(df1, ftable(c, a, b))
      b 0 1
c  a       
5  11   0 0
   13   0 0
   15   0 0
   17   1 0
   18   0 0
   19   0 0
   20   0 1
10 11   0 0
   13   0 0
   15   0 1
   17   1 0
   18   0 1
   19   0 0
   20   0 0
15 11   1 0
   13   0 1
   15   0 0
   17   0 1
   18   0 0
   19   1 0
   20   1 0
```

but what I want is this:

```
    b
c       0     1
  5    17    20
        1     1
  10   17  16.5
        1     2
  15 16.7    15
        3     2
```

***Data:***

```
set.seed(42)
df1 <- data.frame(a=sample(10:20, 10, replace = TRUE),
                  b=sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE),
                  c=sample(c(5, 10, 15), 10, replace = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that objects of class `table` are not really special; they just have this class and `dimnames` attribute:

```
str(table(1:2, 2:3))
#  'table' int [1:2, 1:2] 1 0 0 1
#  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#   ..$ : chr [1:2] "1" "2"
#   ..$ : chr [1:2] "2" "3"
```

So, actually it's easy to convert your result into a table:

```
tmp <- t(outer(0:1, c(5, 10, 15), Vectorize(function(x, y) 
  with(df1, mean(a[b == x & c == y])))))
class(tmp) <- "table"
dimnames(tmp) <- list(c = c("5", "10", "15"), b = c("0", "1"))
tmp
#     b
# c           0        1
#   5  17.00000 20.00000
#   10 17.00000 16.50000
#   15 16.66667 15.00000
```

However, instead of all this you may also run

```
xtabs(a ~ b + c, data = aggregate(a ~ b + c, data = df1, mean))
#    c
# b          5       10       15
#   0 17.00000 17.00000 16.66667
#   1 20.00000 16.50000 15.00000
```

Lastly, to add another row of frequencies right below you may run

```
out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(c(mean, length), function(fun)
  xtabs(a ~ b + c, data = aggregate(a ~ b + c, data = df1, fun))))
out[order(rownames(out)), ]
#    5   10       15
# 0 17 17.0 16.66667
# 0  1  1.0  3.00000
# 1 20 16.5 15.00000
# 1  1  2.0  2.00000
```

Clearly now you may keep adding other functions in addition to `mean` and `length`.

If you want `c` and `b` to be visible or some row names to be empty then an analogous assignment of `dimnames(out)` as that above will work.

Comment: Nice, I've never worked with `xtabs()` so far. But I still need the sub-rows with the frequencies. I can get them according to your code with `xtabs(a ~ b + c, data = aggregate(a ~ b + c, data = df1, length))`. Now we have to combine them. `c(mean, length)` however does not work.

Comment: I'll look into that, but you question not once mentions frequencies, other than their silent presence in the example output, and that changes the question significantly from displaying just the means.

Comment: Given this simple nature of `table`'s, we may simply `rbind` them and sort the rows. The rest is what you want to do with the rows. I don't think there is a more direct solution, at least in base R.